How do I troubleshoot outlook rules not working?
I'm using last version of Windows, with Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise update automatically.
I've created 30+ rules in outlook. All the rules are similar, based on sender, assign a category and move to the folder "categorized".
All the rules are then client-only and they don't stop further processing of other rules.
I run all of them, but I discovered that not all are applied, or not for all email in my inbox and subfolders.
I go to a single rule, and I try to run it manually.
So, I click on "run rules now", I select a rule, I select "inbox folder", I click "include subfolders". I click on "run now"
Nothing happens. No message, rule is not executed, no category is assigned, no email is moved. No error whatsoever.
Not sure what I can do.
I found some suggestion, like "delete and recreate" the rule...well...
I will try to restart everything, but it's weird, if I cannot trust the rules to be applied, it will not be very useful...
Any suggestion?

There is a limit on how many conditions you have. Where this limit is pretty high, if you have 30+ rules, and your rules are complex, its possible that you have actually exceeded the limit somewhere. You can figure out if this is the case, by moving a rule that is not working to the top and see if it starts to work now. If it does, either you indeed have exceeded the limit or a previous rule somehow invalidates your other rule. You can now move the rule that didn't work down a bit and test again until it no longer works. Either the above rule is the problem, or its a limit.

Also to clarify, a condition is one row inside the rule. For example: If Name. contains "John", "Doe" the rule looks for both John and Doe. They are counted as one condition.

Agree with LPChip.
From my perspective, it's a good idea to check each rules you set carefully.
Firstly, the conditions Or and And are completely different cases. As iknow,there will also be a difference in setting rules for senders, because the sender address can be edited, for example, A can use address B to display the name of A (or C), even if you know that the email is from A, however as your settings are to take action on the email address A, the rule will still not work for the email.
Secondly, please check the actions, like creating the same precondition, but creating two rules to move to A and move to B at the same time, then only one of them can be implemented (my test results are preferentially newly created).
Furthermore, maybe you'll want to integrate some rules, and besides, if you have some rules that don't exist for the implementation object, it will also cause the rules to not work. For example, if you want to move an email to a custom folder C, but you deleted or moved folder C, the rule doesn't work.
Finally, please Check the rule quota, Outlook has a limit on the amount of storage space that a rule can use. Make sure your rules are within this limit.
In addition, i find some similar threads you may want to get some inspirations from.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/rules-in-outlook-dont-work-well-or-dont-work-at/2da173df-7f7b-496f-b4b1-b4d1cad02a77
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/177010/outlook-365-inbox-rules-not-working

